# Converting std::vector to vector of item superclass

Tags: c++, generics, vector, casting, covariance

I have two classes, class `Subclass` inherits from the class `Superclass`:

```
class Superclass { /* … */ };
class Subclass : public Superclass { /* … */ };
```

Somewhere in the code, I also have a vector of `Subclass *`. I need to use vectors, since I want to avoid another allocation of list structures and a vector is returned by some other function:

```
std::vector<Subclass *> &myVector = getMyVector();
```

And I also have a function, let's call it `printSuperclasses`, that is taking an argument with type `std::vector<Superclass *> &`. How can I pass the vector shown above to the function? Using `static_cast` does not work and I would like to avoid using `reinterpret_cast`.

```
void printSuperclasses(std::vector<Superclass *> const &);
//                     ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
//                          or another type?
```

If I understand it correctly, both vectors of `Superclass *` and `Subclass *` should be represented in the same way in memory (Are they?), so I should be able to convert from the later to the first. Is there a way to do it in C++ *safely*? Should the function receive it not as a vector, but as something different (iterators etc.)?

Comment: You need to create a new vector; `vector<Superclass>` and `vector<Subclass>`  are entirely unrelated types. Or, change the interface for the function you mentioned. (How something is represented in memory is irrelevant.)

Comment: Maybe you should not have `std::vector<Subclass *> myVector;` at all but `std::vector<Superclass *> myVector;`, then the problem vanishes. Any `Subclass` object is also a `Superclass` object.

Comment: @Jabberwocky, well, that would require casting each of the items when I need to call `Subclass`-specific methods.

Comment: Would using iterators be an option?

Comment: It would be. Could you show us an example in an answer?

Comment: What does said function do, and how does it do it?

Comment: It only processes the items of the vector, without any modification. Let's suppose that it print some information from the items.

Comment: @ jiwopene If the argument is taken as a vector of the parent class, you can't possibly have to call child class specific methods inside :) Moreover, in order to use polymorphism as @Jabberwocky mentioned, your parent class has to be polymorphic !

Comment: In the function that I am calling, only `Superclass` methods are used. But at other places in the code, even `Subclass` methods are required to be available on the vector items.

Comment: `std::vector<Superclass *>(myVector.begin(), myVector.end())`?

Comment: @jiwopene What I meant with iterators is that you can [do this](https://godbolt.org/z/P84448hs8) but you _probably_ should use polymorphism

Comment: _well, that would require casting each of the items when I need to call Subclass-specific methods_ That's what virtual functions are for.

Answer (score 1):

You can't safely pass a `std::vector<Subclass *>` to a function taking `std::vector<Superclass *> &`.

What if it did the following?

```
class Other : public Superclass {};

void takesSuperclass(std::vector<Superclass *> & vec)
{
    vec.push_back(new Other);
}
```

Now you may think to yourself, but *my* function doesn't do that. And you might be right, but you haven't told the type system that.

If you want to pass all kinds of ranges of pointers to `takesSuperclass`, then you could make it a template

```
template<typename Supers>
auto takesSuperClass(Supers && supers)
```

In C++20, you can reasonably enforce those requirements

```
template<typename T>
using ptr_element_t = typename std::pointer_traits<T>::element_type;

template<typename Derived, typename Base>
concept derived_ptr = std::derived_from<ptr_element_t<Derived>, ptr_element_t<Base>>;

template<std::ranges::range Range>
requires derived_ptr<std::ranges::range_value_t<Range>, Super *>
auto takesSuperClass(Range supers)
```

If you don't want to have a template, you can also do some type-erasure, with e.g. [`boost::any_range`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/ranges/any_range.html)

```
void takesSuperclass(boost::any_range<Super *, boost::forward_traversal_tag> supers)
```

Comment: Don't I tell it to the type system when I add `const` to the parameter?

Comment: @jiwopene you would if there were a converting constructor `template<typename To> template<typename From> std::vector<To>::vector(const std::vector<From> & from)`, but there isn't

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change the signature of the function `printSuperclasses`, I would suggest the following. Write a wrapper function, which takes iterators as arguments, and then construct a vector inside that function, which will later be passed to the function you mentioned. This could be done like this

```
template<class Iter>
void printSuperclasses(Iter first, Iter last)
{
    std::vector<Superclass*> superclass_vec(first, last);
    printSuperclasses(superclass_vec);
}
```

The function will be able to convert the pointers if the `Iter` is a iterator of a vector of pointers of any subclass of `Superclass`.

The function would be called like this.

```
std::vector<Subclass*> subclass_vec;  // not initialized, but it is not important in the case of example.
printSuperclasses(subclass_vec.begin(), subclass_vec.end());
```

Comment: You can also make another function template that takes vector of any type and calls the iterator-taking function from the answer.